# Run .sql file with Inno Setup

Tags: mysql, sql, inno-setup, heidisql

I am trying to run `.sql` file using Inno Setup.

```
[Run]
Filename: "C:\Program Files\HeidiSQL\heidisql.exe"; \
    Parameters: "-u root -p Password -h localhost --execute=""G20 Standard.sql"""; \
    WorkingDir: {app}; StatusMsg: Loading Database; Flags: runhidden
```

It loads the `g20 standard.sql` in HeidiSQL, but it's not executing that file. It gives error:

> Please specify directory to watch.

I can close [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxWIx.png) and [execute file manual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otg7x.png)  after.

This error coming from HeidiSQL part as HeidiSQL icon appears in Windows taskbar and I can minimise that fault by clicking on icon.

What could be that I am missing here?
As it looks like error coming from HeidiSQL, should I move this question to that market instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not see any `--execute` switch in [HeidiSQL documentation](https://www.heidisql.com/help.php) --- Actually there does not seem to be any way to execute `.sql` script from HeidiSQL command-line.

You should use MySQL to execute your `.sql`:

- [MySQL install and load database on Inno Setup script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19298667/850848)
- [MySQL query in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44249388/850848)
- [Calling MySQL from inside an Inno Setup project](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2201115/850848)

Comment: That's might be the case unfortunately. Thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score -1):

HeidiSQL can of course be run with an .sql file name on the command line, but you have to remove that --execute stuff around that file, and the file should have a complete path:

```
Filename: "C:\Program Files\HeidiSQL\heidisql.exe"; \
    Parameters: "-u root -p Password -h localhost ""{app}G20 Standard.sql"""; \
    WorkingDir: {app}; StatusMsg: Loading Database; Flags: runhidden
```

On the other hand, if you don't want a visible window, it makes more sense to run an .sql file through `mysql.exe`.

Comment: But that only loads the `.sql` to HeidiSQL window. OP wants to execute the SQL (and presumably in a hidden way).

Comment: Oh yes, you're right. Automatically *running* an .sql file is actually not possible with HeidiSQL, there is no command line parameter for that. Go and use mysql.exe instead, with endless possibilities.